# Group Policy can't be overruled

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have 2 different GPOs in this example, one is directly under the Domain - Global GPO - and one is burried down in an User OU - Custom GPO.

In my Global GPO I have set the Setting "Local Area Network (LAN) settings" to yes. This Setting is located unter User Configuration - Preferences - Control Panel Settings - Internet Settings - Internet Explorer 10: Internet Explorer 10 - Connections.

This Setting works just fine.

Now in my Custom GPO I have set the Setting "Local Area Network (LAN) settings" to no, and it does not override my Global GPO. I even tried to set it to forced and it didn't change anything.

When I enter gpresult on an User affected by Custom GPO, it shows that the GPO is applied however, it shows Global GPO as the winning GPO.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `I even tried to set it to forced` Why would you do that? The purpose of Force is for a higher-level GPO to override a lower-level GPO.

Comment: What's the sequence of the GPOs being applied to that GPO?

Answer (score 0):

I will build an deny group which will deny the Global GPO.

Answer (score 0):

The GPO in the root folder are executed last. Any GPO higher under any other OU are applied first.

Your GPO work as intended, it apply a No and the last's one apply a Yes to your settings.

In the domain wide GPO you have the right solution to bind it to a group to deny it to applied. You could make a WMI filter too. You could have moved the Global GPO to your user OU, where your other GPO are, and change the execution order too.